# android map v2 gms start Intent in onInfoWindowClick

Tags: android, maps

I try to start an Intent in `onInfoWindowClick`, but it freezes:

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
    Context context = parentActivity.getApplicationContext();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, HouseDetailActivity.class);

    parentActivity.startChildActivity("DetailActivity", myIntent);
}
```

If I try to run the same code in

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker)
```

it works perfectly.

Comment: There is no `TabGroupActivity`, nor a `startChildActivity()`, in the Android SDK.

Comment: I have to support old version of android so I use http://androidmaterial.blogspot.ca/2011/04/how-to-us-tab-group-activity-in-android.html

Comment: Bear in mind that `ActivityGroup` has been deprecated for nearly two years.

Comment: but i have to support Android 2.2 and Frament are support on Android 3.0.x and higher.

Comment: Fragments work going back to Android 1.6, if you use the version in the Android Support package.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue. I suspect that the InfoWindow has to be dismissed before anything can proceed, so synchronously changing the view (or the active activity) doesn't work.

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but I solved this by using postDelayed(), like so:

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    marker.hideInfoWindow();
    // Set some variable here so you know which one was clicked
    gMarker = marker;
    myHandler.postDelayed(updateMyMap, 50);
    }
}

private Runnable updateMyMap = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Take some action on the selection here
        setContentView(someView);
    }

};
```